# Magento 2.4.2 - Getting 404 error on both frontend and backend

Tags: magento2.4.2, wamp, windows10

I am trying to install Magento 2.4.2 on my windows machine using wamp. Getting 404 error after installed the Magento successfully.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Steps I followed to resolve the issue:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
php bin/magento config:set web/seo/use_rewrites 0 ------------------------------------------------------------
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer ------------------------------------------------------------------------
php bin/magento cache:clean-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Added virtual host using Wamp

Answer (score 1):

**Option.1**

go to below configuration in admin

**Stores -> Configurations -> General ->Web  -> Search Engine Optimization -> Use Web Server Rewrites**

and **disable**  "Use Web Server Rewrites".

---

**Option.2**

run below command from ssh

```
php bin/magento config:set web/seo/use_rewrites 0 
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

---

if it works for you that mean issue with php rewrite module

hope this helps you :)

Comment: Hi, I have followed the second option. In addition to that, I have set the default mode as a developer.
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Comment: second option works for you?? and yes its better to work in developer mode instead of default mode

Answer (score 0):

Kindly verify the `.htaccess` in base folder pub/static folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your webserver document root folder is set to the `magento/pub` folder

e.g. for Apache

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/magento2/pub/
```

Comment: Since am using windows, I have added this step using wamp's VirtualHost management